# Prove subset of function space is open

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove $S=\{f \in C[0,1]|f(1)<3\}$ is open.With the sup metric.$C[0,1]$ is space of continuous functions.

Attempt let $\epsilon=\text{min} \{3-f(x)|x \in [0,1]\}$

Let $g \in B_{\epsilon}(f)$. Then $|g(x)|<|f(x)-g(x)|+|f(x)|<3-|f(x)|+|f(x)|<3$ so $|g(1)|<3$ and $g \in S$.

Comment: Thinking about this, it seems to me the choice of $\epsilon$ may be wrong. Would it be better to choose $\epsilon=3-f(1)$? Is this proof okay, or what?

Comment: It would be better to choose $\varepsilon = 3 - f(1)$, if for no other reason than your previous $\varepsilon$ may be negative!

Comment: So it would be ok to choose $\epsilon=|\text{min} \{3-f(x)\}|x \in[0,1]\}|$?

Comment: @TheoBendit if I do this does $|g(1)| \leq |f(1)-g(1)|+|f(1)|<3$ complete the proof?

Comment: Choosing the absolute value could allow $\varepsilon = 0$ still, which is not good. Choosing $\varepsilon = 3 - f(1)$ does work, and is guaranteed to be positive. What you wrote is pretty good, but beware over-using absolute values. If $f(1) = -5$ for example, then the middle term in the inequality is larger than $3$. Simply observe that $g(1) - f(1) \le |g(1) - f(1)| \le d(f, g) < \varepsilon = 3 - f(1)$, then cancel the $f(1)$s.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $\xi :C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},$ $\xi (f) =f(1)$ since $$|\xi (f) -\xi (g) |=|f(1) -g(1)|\leqslant ||f-g||$$ the function $\xi $ is continuos hence $S=\xi^{-1} ((-\infty ,3))$ is open as a inverse image of open set by continuous function.